# x11 forwarding on linode server

Tags: debian, x11, linode

I'm not really sure what I'm doing, but I have tried many permutations of the x11 settings that people recommend setting.

my box is a fresh debian 6 install +
apt-get install eclipse
apt-get install xorg
apt-get install xauth
apt-get install x11-apps

$> echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0

$> less /etc/ssh/sshd_config

...

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes

...

Client side, I have installed xming, on mouseover it reads

Xming Server:0.0

and my putty settings are default except

Connection>SSH>X11:

enable x11 forwarding: checked
X display location: 0:0

---

$> xeyes
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
$>

I sort of suspect the problem is in not initializing something something xauth. But I'm a total noob.

help is (obviously) appreciated greatly!

Comment: What's in X0.hosts in your Xming installation directory? Also is there anything in the Xming log?

Comment: it turned out the problem was not server side, I did not have Xming-fonts installed...

Comment: @Zackkenyon Don't forget to answer your own question! :)

Comment: maybe I should delete it instead, does it contain any useful info?